When publishing a .Net 8 Windows Service - how to exclude certain files from the self-contained build
With the following Profile Settings, my C# Win Service creates a self-contained build.

Problem is I need two files to be available in the build dir (and not in the build file itself). One is my app.config file.
I'm reading thru this doc, but can't get it working https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/how-to-exclude-files-from-the-build?view=vs-2022
I do see some temp publish files getting created first; that is, BEFORE it creates the self-contained bundle in my net8.0-windows\publish\win-x64 folder.
For example, I need MyNotificationServiceCore.dll.config to be copied into the final build; this way I can deploy the whole thing as a Service.
I also have a "certificate" folder - and the cert file was getting copied on a POST-BUILD EVENT previously (in my framework version).
Here's my FolderProfile.xml, where I'm trying to add my config file to the :


<Project>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\net8.0-windows\publish\win-x64\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <_TargetId>Folder</_TargetId>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>true</SelfContained>
    <PublishSingleFile>true</PublishSingleFile>
    <IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>true</IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract>
    <PublishReadyToRun>true</PublishReadyToRun>
    <SatelliteResourceLanguages>en</SatelliteResourceLanguages>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Remove="MyNotificationServiceCore.exe.config" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>



Any help appreciated.
